# Trigger event when a link gets visited

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I am developing a web service which will send a url via text message. Once the user taps the URL, it should trigger an update on server. How can I do it?

I am using Python and Flask. Right now, the only thing I can think of is using page views. If page view count changes it will trigger an update on server. Anything better?

Comment: Can you trigger the event via python in your flask controller method (under the @route) for the page that gets visited?

Comment: That's possible. Let me try this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you trigger the event via python in your flask controller method (under the @route) for the page that gets visited?